# Assembly.GetExportedTypes() does not work in .NET 4.0 (same code runs in 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Hey guys (and gals) I'm having a problem using Assembly GetExportedTypes() in .NET 4.0. The same code is working perfectly in a project targeted at an older .NET version.

**NOTE:** **The code works for local assemblies but when trying to open them off a network drive it does not work, that is my problem... It looks to be loading the assembly, but it claims it can't find it when using GetExportedTypes(). Again if I open a dll off my machine it works, this error only occurs with dlls located on network drives **

**EDIT:** The error is thrown on GetExportedTypes

**The Code:**

```
        Assembly assembly;
        Type[] t;

        assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPathOpenFileDialog.FileName.ToString());

        t = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
```

**The Error:**
Could not load file or assembly '****.***.*********.****.*****, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

*(I used asterisks to hide personal information - the file name)*

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, found out the issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way certain security policies are handled was changed in .NET 4.0. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee677170.aspx) should provide some background.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I have: <runtime> <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/> </runtime> in my config, I also tried a few other things mentioned in that post. Prior to doing that the error was saying that I needed to add this to my config to give it the ok. Now that I've done that I get the error shown above.